# How can one create a Spring-XD processor module to filter messages to the output channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-xd

There are lots of examples of how to write transformers etc in java but nothing about filters (except the script type filters, but I want to use a java method).

I'd like to create a custom java filter to filter the payload of a message from a source to a sink.

The examples of filters all refer to an expression.

(How) can I tell the context to execute a java method in a specified class as the expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, what you need to implement the custom Processor Module. Just follow with Custom Transformer sample from [Spring XD Guilde](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#creating-a-processor-module)

The custom `Selector` for filter:

```
public class MySelector implements MessageSelector {

     boolean accept(Message<?> message) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Module ctx `myfilter.xml`:

```
<channel id="input"/>

<filter input-channel="input" output-channel="output">
    <beans:bean class="custom.MySelector" />
</filter>

<channel id="output"/>
```

Package your class to the jar and place everything to the dir `${xd.home}/modules/processors/myfilter` with structure:

```
/myfilter
   /config
      myfilter.xml
   /lib
      myfilter.jar
```

Test it like this:

```
xd:> stream create --name filtertest --definition "http | myfilter | log"
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @Artem. I'm a little new to spring integration and xd. I did see the Example you mentioned an was a bit frustrated that nothing was said about filters :) It was the MessageSelector implementation that did it for me.